# How to break up an Axios call in REACTJS in multiple files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

My project is making Axios calls in multiple files and I want to modulate it and pass the call as a prop to the other files that need it.

Here is my *componentDidMount()* method that has the call:

```
 componentDidMount () {
 document.body.style = 'background: #b8bab2;'
// Retrieve projects data
 axios.get('/env?var=READER_HOSTNAME').then(response => {
  return axios.get(`${response.data.var}/graphql?query=${queries.allProjects()}`)
 }).then(response => {
  this.setState({
    projects: response.data.data.projects,
    visible: response.data.data.projects,
    isLoaded: true
  })
 })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default withData = MyComponent => {
  return class MyComponentWithData extends Component {
    state = { projects: null, visible: null, isLoaded: false }

    componentDidMount() {
      // Retrieve projects data
      axios.get('/env?var=READER_HOSTNAME')
        .then(response => {
          return axios.get(`${response.data.var}/graphql?query=${queries.allProjects()}`)
        }).then(response => {
          const { projects } = response.data.data
          this.setState({
            projects,
            visible: projects,
            isLoaded: true
          })
        })
    }

    render() {
      const { projects, visible, isLoaded } = this.state
      if (!isLoaded) {
        return null
      }
      return (
        <MyComponent
          {...this.props}
          projects={projects}
          visible={visible}
          isLoaded={isLoaded}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Import `withData` into the component you want to use it with like so:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  // ... component code
}
export default withData(SomeComponent)
```